# Export pdf document with php using dompdf

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.3, dompdf

I have a question for you, so I tried to export pdf document with php using dompdf,all goes well but when I send php variables to display it's add to the end and the beginning  .%27

```
public function generateTitlePage($number_cadastral='')
{
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = <<<HTML
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" href="TitlePage.css"  />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: right; padding-right:100px;">
                Number:$number_cadastral
                <div style="width: 150px;margin-left: 535px;size:1;"><hr style="margin:0px;"></div>
            </div>
            <div>
      </body>
        </html>
   HTML;

    $dompdf->load_html($html);
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
```

In this case variable $number_cadastral is preceded .%27, so the result will be: %27.787883434.%27.Why add this %27??Help me please

Comment: better put that all html in view and use $html = $this->load->view('html_view_name',$data,TRUE); and use that html to create pdf

Comment: did you check that your number doesn't contain any spaces?

Comment: I don't really like the selected answer, it hacks around the problem without actually fixing it. Did you check that your variable doesn't contain extra characters. %27 appears to be a single quote URL-encoded. Try echoing out the `$html` variable instead of running it through dompdf and see what comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $number_cadastral = ($number_cadastral != "")?preg_replace('/[%]+/','', $number_cadastral):"";
    public function generateTitlePage($number_cadastral){
        $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
        $html = '
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" media="screen" href="TitlePage.css"  />
            </head>
            <body>
                <div style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: right; padding-right:100px;">
                    Number:'.$number_cadastral.'
                    <div style="width: 150px;margin-left: 535px;size:1;"><hr style="margin:0px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div>
          </body>
            </html>
       ';

        $dompdf->load_html($html);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
    }
?>
```

Try this code.

Comment: @erhaneluion did you check is there a space before 27?

Comment: Yes, there no blank spaces

Comment: The pdf doesn't open now I think is from preg_replace function

Comment: But what is thhe best regex to drop .%27

Comment: @erhaneluion Glad that it helped. I think the above mentioned one is one of the good one:)