# Special characters with dompdf and php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, php-5.3, dompdf

I have a question: I tried to export a pdf with dompdf and php but I can't do this and I dont understand where is my problem, so my code is:

```
public function generateTitlePage($company)
{
    $this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
    $html='
        <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style="margin-top:20px;text-align: center;font-weight: bold">
                Company:'.$company.'
            </div>
        </body>
        <html>'; 
    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = stripslashes($html);
    $dompdf->load_html($html, 'UTF-8');
    $dompdf->set_paper('a4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream("welcome.pdf");
}
```

For example if I have ă in my pdf this symbol is converted in : %C4%83

Comment: Asking the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25569597/264628) [multiple times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25542424/264628) is not how to use StackOverflow. You should limit yourself to one question, respond to comments, and edit your question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find similar and I found, that many other users has the same problem with UTF-8 encoding. They found solution by changing `mbstring.encoding_translation` to `On` in `php.ini` configuration file:

```
mbstring.encoding_translation = On
```

Or for some helped [`utf8_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php) function:

```
$dompdf->load_html(utf8_decode($html), 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: I changed, the situation reste the same

Comment: Also try the second alternative.

Comment: And probably irrelevant question, but is your PHP file saved in UTF8 encoding? And why are you using stripslashes?

Comment: My file is saved in UTF8 I removed stripslashes